# Why does Entity keep making new databases?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I'm doing a project utilizing Entity Framework's Code-First approach. Things were going fine, until we changed the location of where the database is created:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\ProjectsV12;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Schema.Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
```

And then we set `DataDirectory`:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\TestDB\\");
```

Now, we have several databases with names `SCHEMA_TEST_*`, where the `*` is some random number(I'm sure it's not random, but I hadn't figured out how it's generated). Also, I'm not sure what is causing the creation of another database, rather than the first created. Why is it creating the other databases, and why can't it just be called `Schema.Test` like I'd mentioned in the `connectionString`?

**UPDATE**

When I remove the `AttachDbFilename` section of the connection string, it all appears to go back to normal no matter what I do. Though, admittedly, I'm still not sure how or why the extra databases are created. Though, it seems to be done every time there's a change in the schema. Which shouldn't happen since, we are utilizing migrations.

Comment: Are the database files that will be created in the app directory write protected?

Comment: EntityFramework does track Schema Changes and I suspect that is what is creating your random number extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your connection string using a layout like this:

```
<add connectionString="Server=yourServer;Database=yourDB;Integrated Security=true" name="DefaultConnection" PoviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Here is a link to a list with lots of examples of connection strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have set your DataDirectory using the following code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", 
     Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) 
     + "\\TestDB\\");
```

So effectively your DataDirectory values is `someval\\TestDB\\`

This you use in your connectionString as

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Schema.Test.mdf;
```

So won't the final DbFilename comes to `someval\\TestDB\\\Schema.Test.mdf` ? Notice the extra `\` before Schema.Test.mdf

I am not sure of this, but just a general observation suggestion this *could* be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This bit of code will turn off entityframework from monitoring your schema changes.  Once you do this you have to fix schema changes your self.

Link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205.aspx

[Stop Entity Framework from modifying database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230053/stop-entity-framework-from-modifying-database)

```
 DbContext = new DataContext();
 DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

Comment: This code will not stop EF from checking schema changes but will disable Entries change detection

Comment: The previous code was not a good example.  If I remember correctly this new snippet should be correct.